# Is a large capacitor required if the power source comes from another board?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

I'm currently designing a power board to convert from 12V to 5V with a buck converter then to 3.3V with a LDO.

Here's the schematic:

[image: Power board schematic]

This power board will be connected to a larger board (see below) with wires between 5 to 10 cm maximum.

Do I need to add some large capacitor, like a 47uF electrolytic or tantalum?

If yes, is it better to put it on the power board or on the board that uses the power?

Here's the schematic of the larger board that will be connected to the power board:

[image: Larger board that will be connected to the power board]

Comment: 5-10 cm isn't that long; do you intend to hot-plug this power connector?

Comment: no, the two boards will be connected with power off then put in an enclosure

Comment: It's better to put it closer to the load since that's how decoupling works.

It's not always necessary but it's nice to have. You can just always make the footprint on the board and not populate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to add some large capacitor (like 47uF electrolytic or
> tantalum) ?

Depends on how tolerant the parts on the board are of ripple, and how much ripple you will have. Since this will probably be hard to determine since the ripple with depend on changes in software, it might be good to leave a spot for the 47uF on the board and install it if it is needed. There should be enough resistance in the cable that it wont be seen by the DC DC converter as "output capacitance".

Comment: Ok, If I understand correctly, most of the ripple will come from the buck convertor so I can add a capacitor on the 5V rail on the board and install it if needed. Do you think I need to add one also for the 12V and 3.3V ?